# How can I change the color of my prompt in zsh (different from normal text)?

Tags: colors, zsh, prompt

To recognize better the start and the end of output on a commandline, I want to change the color of my prompt, so that it is visibly different from the programs output. As I use zsh, can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here's an example of how to set a red prompt:

```
PS1=$'\e[0;31m$ \e[0m'
```

The magic is the `\e[0;31m` (turn on red foreground) and `\e[0m` (turn off character attributes). These are called escape sequences. Different escape sequences give you different results, from absolute cursor positioning, to color, to being able to change the title bar of your window, and so on.

For more on escape sequences, see [the wikipedia entry on ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: I am using PROMPT='[%!]' in my .zshrc. How can you color it? I run unsuccessfully PROMPT='\e[0;31m[%!] \e[0m' in my .zshrc.

Comment: @erikb85: why do you say it's wrong? Is there something I can do to make the answer better? For me, doing the above gives me a red dollar sign, so I don't understand why you think it's wrong.

Comment: It is working, but the $ before the string make zshrc to glitch. The text is put on the left when I use tabulation. I prefer @Joe the Person answer

Comment: I agree @Moebius I wanted this one to work it was clear and simple, but it completely messes up the tab on cd

Comment: I thought zsh didn't need crazy weird ANSI escape stuff...there must be a better answer...

Comment: Your answer is missing the `%{` and `%}` markers that identify the escape sequences.  Without these, `zsh` will count escape sequences as part of the display length of your prompt, and you'll end up with bizarre cursor positioning and line editor behavior on longer commands.  See `man zshmisc`, EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES, Visual Effects.  Not all shells require you do this; Korn shell, for example, parses common escape sequences in the PS1 string (though it will display the aforementioned problem on sequences, usually unusual ones, that it doesn't identify correctly).

Answer (score 434):

Put this in `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
autoload -U colors && colors
PS1="%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%m %{$fg[yellow]%}%~ %{$reset_color%}%% "
```

Supported Colors:
`red`, `blue`, `green`, `cyan`, `yellow`, `magenta`, `black`, & `white` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159856/how-do-zsh-ansi-colour-codes-work)) although different computers may have different valid options.

Surround color codes (and any other non-printable chars) with `%{....%}`. This is for the text wrapping to work correctly.

Additionally, here is how you can get this to work with the directory-trimming from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273567/3268).

```sh
PS1="%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%m %{$fg[yellow]%}%(5~|%-1~/.../%3~|%4~) %{$reset_color%}%% "
```

Comment: Agreed, by far the superior answer (luckily this answer was the third Google result ;)

Comment: not working for me. :(
`zsh: colors: function definition file not found`

Comment: Are you using ZSH4? I don't think it works on versions less than 4.3.11. If you have the latest version maybe it is not using the right files.

Comment: What are the valid color values?

Comment: the `%{...%}` means that the content will be interpreted as a literal escape sequence, so the cursor wont move while printing the sequence. If you dont use this, the color codes can actually move the cursor and produce undesired effects. This is documented in the `Visual Effects` section in [zshmisc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshmisc)

Comment: do you mind explaining in detail what all the symbols in your prompt are doing or at least a link to a reference? e.g. what is are the `%` outside doing? Also what does things like `{$fg...}` etc do?

its difficult to understand your answer because it assumes to much knowledge of shells or zsh. Can you make it a little bit more self contained or link to references please?

Comment: As of Feb 2023, the macOS Ventura 13.1 Terminal has no response to the `%{$fg[red]%}%n` command for color change. I had to use `%F{red}%n` instead. Not sure why. It could be because of a version update.

Answer (score 106):

Zsh comes with colored prompts builtin. Try

```
autoload -U promptinit && promptinit
```

and then `prompt -l` lists available prompts, `-p fire` previews the "fire" prompt, `-s fire` sets it.

When you are ready to add a prompt add something like this below the autoload line above:

```
prompt fade red
```

Comment: Is there a way to color all the themes? I like the walters prompt but would like it in red.

Comment: this sounded great but I don't like any of these options...

Answer (score 51):

The answer by Bryan Oakley above has a glitch as it has already been pointed out and the solution offered by Andrew Marshall though it does not carry the glitch, nevertheless it does not make it obvious for too much customization on the colors used.

As macOS Catalina asks for zsh to be the default shell from now on, I think several more people may want to customize their prompt and might be coming here for an answer. So, I thought I would try to give a broader summary and touch upon other very closely-related notions that allow more customization.

**3-Digit Codes for Various Colors.**
First of all, here we can find 3-digit codes for various colors: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124409/194343.
For example, 214 is some kind of orange color.

**Foreground and Background.**
The other key information is that for **F**oreground and bac**K**ground colors one can define what they want with **F** and **K** respectively. Source is zsh manual on visual effects: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects

So, for example, the following two commands

```
autoload -U colors && colors
export PS1="%F{214}%K{000}%m%F{015}%K{000}:%F{039}%K{000}%~%F{015}%K{000}\$ "
```

present the hostname in orange with black background, followed by a colon in white with black background, followed by the current working directory in bright blue with black background, followed by the dollar sign in white with black background.

More related information is found below.

**Prompt information on the right-hand side.** For example, adding a timestamp. See https://superuser.com/a/1251045/290299. Of course, this can be color-coded, for example with some light blue/purple-ish color, like this:

```
RPROMPT="%F{111}%K{000}[%D{%f/%m/%y}|%@]"
```

**Colors for `ls`.** After reading the manual for ls, one for example can activate the colors for `ls` using the following two commands:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gafacadabaegedabagacad
```

Finally, as a last remark that I have not tested as I am happy with my configuration, another avenue might be for someone to install the port `coreutils` from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) and then use `gdircolors` (source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174596/194343). (I may edit this last part in the future as all the above are related pieces that make every-day life much more fun and easier to cope with.)

Comment: This is an immensely helpful answer. Thanks for putting this together.

Answer (score 34):

I don't think the `autoload -U colors && colors` is needed anymore and one can simply do:

```
PS1="%{%F{red}%}%n%{%f%}@%{%F{blue}%}%m %{%F{yellow}%}%~ %{$%f%}%% "
```

to achieve the same result as [FireDude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689765/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-prompt-in-zsh-different-from-normal-text#2534676). See the [ZSH documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#SEC59) for more info.

Comment: FYI. I've just tried in Ubunutu 11.04 and colors didn't work for me without `autoload -U colors && colors`

Comment: Weird. Works for me on OS X & Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall Yes, but it is more likely to work with `autoload` on.

Comment: @fireDude67 How to set `autoload on` ?

Comment: @balki autoload -U colors && colors

Comment: The `autoload` is not needed for me with Debian and `zsh 4.3.17 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)` - also check out the [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects) mentioned above for some cool effects, for example `%K (%k)` for background color. Thanks for this, Mr. Marshall.

Comment: I needed the `autoload` in Crunchbang (essentially Debian) and `zsh 4.3.17 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: If you don't need `autoload -U colors`, that means that your distro already has it in some other zsh initialization file. You should still include it in scripts you intend to share with others.

Answer (score 23):

Try my favorite:
put in

```
~/.zshrc
```

this line:

```
PROMPT='%F{240}%n%F{red}@%F{green}%m:%F{141}%d$ %F{reset}'
```

don't forget

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

to test the changes

you can change the colors/color codes, of course :-)

Comment: Only this works for me, after try hundreds PS1's that they all not works

Answer (score 9):

In order to not waste space in the terminal with special characters to pieces of information, you can differentiate information using multiple colors.

Eg. in order to get this desired effect:

[image: Desired Outcome]

You can do the following to your prompt:

```
PROMPT='%F{magenta}${PWD/#$HOME/~} %F{green}${vcs_info_msg_0_} %F{cyan}$%F{reset_color} '
```

The way it works is every time you set a color using `$F{myColor}` the color from that point onward will stick to that. It's important to add in `%{reset_color}` at the end so that the input text goes back to the original color (or you could set it to something else if you'd like).

Answer (score 7):

**Debian/Ubuntu/Raspberry Pi OS style bash prompt:**

```
autoload -U colors && colors
PS1="%B%F{034}%n@%m%f%b:%B%F{019}%~ %#%f%b "
```

[image: Screen shot]

Not entirely sure if `autoload -U colors && colors` is necessary but I did need it when I was using `$fg[...]` instead of `%F{...}`.
In my example;

- %F(%f) starts(stops) foreground color - I've used 256COLOR values but you could also use hex for example, I've used normal green `%F{034}` but `%F{#00aa00}` works too
- %B(%b) starts(stops) bold
- %n $USERNAME
- %m short machine name
- %~ logged in/working directory with ~ if in home directory
- %# display % if normal user or # if su

Edit: Tested on macOS Big Sur, Monterey and Ventura. Unsure of earlier zsh versions but Ventura 13.0 is zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)

Answer (score 5):

I have found that, with zsh5 (the default one on Debian Jessie), all those solutions works:

- `$'\e[00m`
- `$fg[white]`
- `$fg{white}`

Now, they have a problem: they will move the cursor, resulting in ugly decal when tabbing (for auto-completion). The solution is simply to surround the escape sequences with `%{FOOBAR%}`. Took me a while to figure this.
For 2nd and 3rd solutions loading `colors` module is mandatory.
To keep the 1st solution readable, just define variables for the colors you use.

Answer (score 5):

To get a prompt with the color depending on the last command’s exit status, you could use this:

```
PS1='%(?.%F{green}.%F{red})%n@%m:%~%# %f'
```

Just add this line to your `~/.zshrc`.

The [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) lists possible placeholders.

Comment: `PS1='%(?.%F{green}.%F{red})%n@%m:%F{141}%d$ %F{reset}'` I went with this to add the PWD.

Answer (score 4):

To complement all of the above answers another convenient trick is to place the coloured prompt settings into a zsh function. There you may define local variables to alias longer commands, e.g. `rc=$reset_color` or define your own colour variables. Don't forget to place it into your `.zshrc` file and call the function you have defined:

```
# Coloured prompt
autoload -U colors && colors
function myprompt {
  local rc=$reset_color
  export PS1="%F{cyan}%n%{$rc%}@%F{green}%m%{$rc%}:%F{magenta}%~%{$rc%}%# "
}
myprompt
```

Answer (score 1):

man zshall and search for PROMPT EXPANSION

After reading the existing answers here, several of them are conflicting.  I've tried the various approaches on systems running zsh 4.2 and 5+ and found that the reason these answers are conflicting is that they do not say which version of ZSH they are targeted at.  Different versions use different syntax for this and some of them require various autoloads.

So, the best bet is probably to man zshall and search for PROMPT EXPANSION to find out all the rules for your particular installation of zsh.  Note in the comments, things like "I use Ubuntu 11.04 or 10.4 or OSX" Are not very meaningful as it's unclear which version of ZSH you are using.  Ubuntu 11.04 does not imply a newer version of ZSH than ubuntu 10.04.  There may be any number of reasons that an older version was installed.  For that matter a newer version of ZSH does not imply which syntax to use without knowing which version of ZSH it is.