# How do zsh ansi colour codes work?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I want to make my hostname in my terminal orange. How do I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First off, I'm not sure what terminal you're using or if it will even support the color orange. Mine supports the following: Red, Blue, Green, Cyan, Yellow, Magenta, Black & White. And here's how I get colors in my terminal:

---

You need to first load the colors using `autoload`. I use the following to load the colors and assign them to meaningful names

```
#load colors
autoload colors && colors
for COLOR in RED GREEN YELLOW BLUE MAGENTA CYAN BLACK WHITE; do
    eval $COLOR='%{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}'  #wrap colours between %{ %} to avoid weird gaps in autocomplete
    eval BOLD_$COLOR='%{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}'
done
eval RESET='%{$reset_color%}'
```

You can set the hostname in your prompt using the `%m` string. So to set, say a red hostname, you'd do

```
${RED}%m${WHITE}\>
```

which will print something like `bneil.so>`

Comment: This is a great snippet @yoda. Do you know if there is a way to 1) Know what colors are loaded in autoload colors && colors? 2) Know what colors are supported by your terminal?

Comment: These are the colors that are loaded by `autoload`. That little loop merely renames them to more intuitive color names (e.g., `RED` instead of `fg_no_bold_RED` or something like that). If you're running Mac OS X 10.6 and below, the default Terminal.app will support only 16 colors. You can download `iterm2` for Mac which is a great terminal and supports 256 colors. With OS X 10.7, I think Terminal.app supports 256 colors (although I can't verify as I haven't upgraded). You can also use [this handy script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349) to see how many colors it supports.

Comment: @yoda, I added the percent wrapping to the RESET as well.  It has the same "weird gap" issue for me otherwise.

Comment: When I try to use this first snippet I get the error: `command not found: autocomplete`

Answer (score 51):

Running the following code in your terminal should tell you whether your terminal supports 256 colors.

```sh
for COLOR in {0..255} 
do
    for STYLE in "38;5"
    do 
        TAG="\033[${STYLE};${COLOR}m"
        STR="${STYLE};${COLOR}"
        echo -ne "${TAG}${STR}${NONE}  "
    done
    echo
done
```

it also shows you the code for each color in the form `38;5;x` where `x` is the code for one of the 256 available colors.
Also, note that changing the `"38;5"` to `"48;5"` will show you the background color equivalent. You can then use any colors you like to make up the prompt as previously mentioned.

Comment: What is the value of `${NONE}`?

Answer (score 4):

Print

```
<ESC>[33mHostname<ESC>[0m
```

Being  the escape character \x1b