# Adding timestamp to each line on Zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just fresh installed Sierra and wanted to use zsh with oh-my-zsh and power shell...

I ended up with a terminal like this:

[image]

But I want to add a timestamp to every output. Semething linke:

`[14:23] acytryn ~ Projects %`

Is there a way to do this with zsh?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I've found it more non-destructive to actually prepend the time to the existing prompt without overriding it completely. This makes it work with any existing theme without interfering with its styling.

Add this at the end of your `.zshrc` file. You can type the command `nano ~/.zshrc` to edit it using `nano`:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[yellow]%}[%D{%f/%m/%y} %D{%L:%M:%S}] '$PROMPT
```

I use cloud theme, so this gives me:

[image]

It retains the current theme. You can also add some styling to the timestamp, by changing the color, or even the format. You may refer to the official Zsh Date and Time formatting linked here: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Date-and-time. This uses Linux's strftime3 (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) to format the Date (%D) string.

Make sure to reload your `.zshrc` file by typing:

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

or

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: How to put this on the right hand side of the screen?

Comment: If you just want a 24 hour timestamp, you can use this `PROMPT='%{$fg[yellow]%}[%D{%T}] '$PROMPT`

Comment: A bit of simplification: you can remove the middle `} %D{` part. So you'd have `PROMPT='%{$fg[yellow]%}[%D{%f/%m/%y %L:%M:%S}] '$PROMPT`. Works for me this way.

Comment: what if I just want unix timestamp prepended? How would I do that?

Comment: @wcyn How can I add time stamp to right side and took time at the end of left side things?

Comment: fun fact ab this one. if you ever resource your .zshrc your prompt just grows and growsss

Comment: @Farshad have a look at @ehacinom's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60842361/2878244 Essentially, you need to use `RPROMPT` instead of `PROMPT`

Answer (score 26):

If you want it on the right side:

```
RPROMPT="[%D{%f/%m/%y} | %D{%L:%M:%S}]"
```

https://gist.github.com/zulhfreelancer/9c410cad5efa9c5f7c74cd0849765865

Comment: how can I add name of day to this command? and the takcing time to the end of left side

Answer (score 19):

Yes.
Just open your `~/.zshrc` and add this line at the end of it (using `nano ~/.zshrc` command in terminal, for example):

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[yellow]%}[%*] '$PROMPT
```

And you'll get it like this:

[image]

You can change `[%*]` section to get other formats:

```
 %D     The date in yy-mm-dd format.
 %T     Current time of day, in 24-hour format.
 %t %@  Current time of day, in 12-hour, am/pm format.
 %*     Current time of day in 24-hour format, with seconds.
 %w     The date in day-dd format.
 %W     The date in mm/dd/yy format.
```

Answer (score 4):

add this to the bottom of your `~/.zsh` file:

```
PROMPT='[%T] %n ~ %d %%'
```

Comment: I don't have .zsh file... should it be on .zshrc? (It didn't work anyway)

Comment: when you say "it didn't work anyway", what didn't work?  putting it in the .zshrc or even typing "`PROMPT='[%T] %n ~ %d %%'`" into your zsh shell to try it out?

Comment: I added to the last file of .zshrc file, runned `source ~/.zshrc` but nothing changed. I am using powerline-shell, I dont know if that interferes somehow. Also, pasting that into prompt directly has no output

Comment: powerline-shell uses a `precmd` function to dynamically set the value of `PROMPT` prior to it being displayed. You need to follow the instructions at https://github.com/banga/powerline-shell to modify your prompt.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
PROMPT='%F{219}[%D{%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S}]%f '$PROMPT
```

Thanks to @wcyn for his great answer.
I made it more readable by:

1. Removing the second D
2. Changing the hours format to 24-hour format: from L to H
3. Changing the day format to 2 digits: from f to d
4. Changing the coloring format

**Explanation**

To color text, use this syntax:

```
%F{color_code}My_Text%f
```

Specifically, color code 219 sets a light purple color. You can discover the color encodings with [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771593/9778828)