# How to use escape sequences in a ZSH prompt for truecolor or bold?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, zshrc, konsole

I am in the middle of customizing my ZSH prompt but am seemingly unable to use escape sequences to tell Konsole to use bold text or a specific RGB color.

I know about the built in formatting options in ZSH, like `%F{000} %f`, but as far as I know, those options only allow access to the defaults(red, blue, etc) and the 256 color palette. While `%B %b`, the built-in option for bold, does work, it seems limited to just one color.

What I want to be able to do is color a specific section of the prompt using all RGB colors and/or make it bold. From what I could find, something like this should work:

```
PS1="%{\e[38;0;255;0;255m%}%M >:%{\e[0m%}"
```

That should give me a pink prompt like this:

```
HOSTNAME >:
```

But what I get is this:

```
\e[38;0;255;0;255mHOSTNAME >:\e[0m
```

I have tried different escape sequences like `\033` `\x1b`, but nothing seems to work.

So, how do I properly use escape sequences in ZSH prompts?

Specifics:

OpenSUSE Tumbleweed KDE

Konsole --version 16.12.0 (Keyboard:XFree 4)

ZSH --version 5.3

Comment: FWIW, "all RGB colors" is not a thing; while the palete may be able to be changed it's still a fixed set: http://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html

Comment: That is 88-no-million or 256 color palettes. Standard [True Color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth#True_color_.2824-bit.29) is only 24bits or ~16 million colors and expressed as a composition of values. Terminals (any of the VT- family, anyway) require indexing into a fixed color palette table.

Comment: I still think it's a fair question - just keep in mind that accessing a color by RGB (without updating the palette itself) is probably not possible.

Comment: Oh, cute. Here are some terminals that do support True Color. This is beyond VT- - https://deductivelabs.com/en/2016/03/using-true-color-vim-tmux/ ; make sure Konsole is on that list.

Comment: @user2864740 Konsole is on the list, I already checked here: https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728

Comment: Note that interactive shell customization is generally a better topic for [unix.se] than Stack Overflow; the latter is narrowly focused on writing software.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change your strings so that zsh evaluates them correctly.

Try changing:

`PS1="%{\e[38;0;255;0;255m%}%M >:%{\e[0m%}"`

To:

`PS1=$'%{\e[38;0;255;0;255m%}%M >:%{\e[0m%}'`

Notice the change from `"` to `'` quotes along with the prepended `$`

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html for more info on substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late for this, but on ZSH, your answer will be:

```bash
PS1="%F{green}%M >:%f"
```

Your original code used the ANSI escape sequences for colour formatting, which might not work correctly in all Zsh terminals. This updated code uses the Zsh-specific prompt escape sequences (%F{color_code} and %K{color_code}) to set the **F**oreground and bac**K**ground colours, respectively.

To apply this you must set it in the .zshrc file located at ~/.zshrc.

Run this to set it automatically (it will not override any existing settings there):

```bash
touch ~/.zshrc && echo '\nPS1="%F{green}%M >:%f"' >> ~/.zshrc && echo "Success";
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159856/how-do-zsh-ansi-colour-codes-work) is a StackOverflow question that answers how the colours work in zsh.

Comment: OP already knew about `%F`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify arbitrary 24-bit colors with `%F` using an RGB triplet.

```
% print -P "%F{#009090}tealish"
tealish
```

(You have to imagine the appropriate color, as I can't reproduce it using text alone.)

Comment: Finally something that works! The `\e[38m` syntax wasn't working for me on Cygwin zsh 5.8

Comment: `\e[38m` is an example of an ANSI terminal escape sequence, and as such only works on an ANSI terminal. `zsh`'s own escapes use whatever is appropriate for the terminal you are actually using.