# How do I change my $PS1 on a Macbook for oh-my-zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to find the PS1 variable in oh-my-zsh and change it so iTerm doesn't look as clogged up. Running the following command:

```
echo $PS1
```

gives me this

```
%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)
```

Additionally, I've attempted to edit the .zshrc file and put

```
export PS1="random-text"
```

but it didn't work. I've tried to look around for the PS1 variable, but couldn't locate it.

If it also helps, I'm running El Capitan on my laptop right now. I couldn't find any similar questions to what I posted so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For answers about the macOS Catalina zsh look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58563434/990971

Comment: Questions about configuring your shell _as a user_ rather than as a developer are generally more on-topic at [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: If like me you ended up here because you need to show the virtual env in Python, the just change your theme in `~/.zshrc` to the following: `ZSH_THEME="kennethreitz"` :-)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Changing your Theme:**

To edit your prompt in oh-my-zsh you need to edit a `PROMPT` variable in your theme instead of `PS1`. In your .zshrc file you will find a line that looks something like this:

```
ZSH_THEME="themename"
```

oh-my-zsh stores these themes in the `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes` folder. If you `ls ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes` you will see a list of themes that you can change. The above theme would be named  `themename.zsh-theme` in this directory.

**Customizing your Theme:**

If you want a simple way to customize your oh-my-zsh theme you can copy a file already in this theme folder and edit that.

To change your prompt simply edit the `PROMPT` variable. For example:

```
PROMPT=">>"
```

This would make two `>`'s your prompt.

I like editing the already existing simple theme. the simple.zsh-theme file looks like this:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[green]%}%~%{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%} '

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="("
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX=")"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY=" ✗"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=" ✔"
```

**Applying the Changes:**

Now just change the theme in your in your .zshrc file:

```
ZSH_THEME="simple"
```

And reload oh-my-zsh with:

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: To create a new theme, it should be added to the [`~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/` directory](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Customization#overriding-and-adding-themes)

Comment: Added to @Devin comment above, here is the official doc about "Overriding and adding new themes" https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Customization

Comment: You don't need any theme. Just in file `.zshrc` add `PROMPT='%. $ '` It should do the work.

Comment: `I like editing the already existing simple theme`: you do not explain how you edit it. Or do you mean edit your `prompt` by using the `simple theme`? You could also write where to put the `theme` variable in the `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 11):

***Important update 1st July, 2021. I saw devote for this answer from yesterday. So the below command might not work anymore. Just try POWERLEVEL10K now.***

For POWERLEVEL9K if you're using it

```
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(dir)
```

PS: Try POWERLEVEL10K, it's much better. trust me