# Different macOS Terminal colors for user input vs. shell output

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

When I have some operations on Mac Terminal, the user's input and the shell's output have the same color

When I have a lot of operations and I want to look back in the history, it is difficult because all the lines of the user's input and shell's output mix together.

I want to specify a different color for the user's input text. How can I do this in macOS Terminal?

- System version: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
- Software: Terminal

[image: shell text color image]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218217/change-output-color-of-terminal-in-mac-to-be-different-from-typed-text-color

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the color of my prompt in zsh (different from normal text)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689765/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-prompt-in-zsh-different-from-normal-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `~/.bash_profile` add this line:

`export PS1='\[\e[1;31m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '`

It will set colors of the prompt. You can read some more about this [here](https://ss64.com/osx/syntax-prompt.html).

You can also change some colors in `Terminal -> Preferences... -> Profiles -> Text`.

Comment: a good solution! it changes the color of prompt, and did distinguish between user's input and shell's output, thanks~

Comment: This changes only the color of prompt. I think what OP really wants is described here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218217/change-output-color-of-terminal-in-mac-to-be-different-from-typed-text-color

Comment: not working!!!!