# zsh prompt configuration for bold colour variants

Tags: command-prompt, zsh, mintty

I have configured my terminal (mintty on Cygwin) to bind colours to certain names, for example

```
# (Excerpt of .minttyrc)
Green=103,252,66
BoldGreen=53,228,11
BoldAsColour=yes
```

This configuration works in that I can, for instance, access these colours, when configuring git or nano. However, when I want to configure my zsh prompt, only the non-bold variants work. I guess that I'm using the wrong syntax to refer to the bold colours. Example:

```
print -P 'X%F{green}ABC%fY'
```

This displays the letters "ABC" in "my" green, but if I do any of the

```
print -P 'X%F{bold green}ABC%fY'
print -P 'X%F{boldgreen}ABC%fY'
print -P 'X%F{bright green}ABC%fY'
print -P 'X%F{brightgreen}ABC%fY'
```

the whole string is displayed in the normal foreground colour, which likely means that the colour name is not recognized.

I also tried

```
print -P 'X%B%F{green}ABC%f%bY'
```

but this does not use the BoldGreen value and instead displays ABC in a - eh - bolder font.

Could someone explain to me, why this happens, and suggest a workaround?

Comment: Check this: [How can I change the color of my prompt in zsh (different from normal text)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689765/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-prompt-in-zsh-different-from-normal-text)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the link. While it doesn't show which color *name* could be used for my problem, it indeed pointed out a workaround by using suitable escape codes: For instance, `print -P $'X\e[0;92mABC%fY'` would display *ABC* in bright green - I was not aware of the 90-97 range of the ANSI colour codes.

Comment: %B and %b does work to bold for me in zsh

Answer (score 1):

You can use the numeric form of `%F` to access the bright versions of the 8 standard colors. This `for`-loop will list each base color with its corresponding bright version:

```sh
for c in {0..7}; do 
  b=$((c+8))
  print -P - "%F{$c}$c%f -> %F{$b}$b%f"
done
```

So, for example, whereas `%F{2}` will give you base green, `%F{10}` will give you bright green.

More info [here under `%F (%f)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects) and [here under `fg=`*colour*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Character-Highlighting).