# how to change the zsh terminal path color?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I use on-my-zsh, how to change the path color?

[image]

here is my config file content in the following

```sh
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="alanpeabody"
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689765/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-prompt-in-zsh-different-from-normal-text)

Comment: By loading a certain theme, you agree to use that theme's coloring. If you want to have different colors, modify the theme (or make a copy of the theme, and modify the copy). If you are mostly concerned about readability, in your concrete case I would change the background colour of your Terminal to one which goes better with your theme than a black one.

Comment: It's also pretty trivial to create your own oh-my-zsh theme. You can see the source (look in the repository you cloned, or [here on github](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/themes/alanpeabody.zsh-theme)). If you don't like the blue, you can change it to something else (specifically check line 3).

Answer (score 2):

First option: Create a custom theme based on your current theme and change the color of the relevant field

```
cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/alanpeabody.zsh-theme ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/alanpeabody-custom.zsh-theme
```

Change zsh terminal theme to your custom theme - edit ~/.zshrc and change **ZSH_THEME="alanpeabody"** to

```
ZSH_THEME="alanpeabody-custom"
```

Edit **~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/alanpeabody-custom.zsh-theme** in order to change the color of the current working directory value, just change the **blue** value to one of the available color names: **black**, **red**, **green**, **yellow**, **blue**, **magenta**, **cyan**, **white** of the line below

```
local pwd='%{$fg[blue]%}%~%{$reset_color%}'
```

Second option:
Copy ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/alanpeabody.zsh-theme content to the bottom of your ~/.zshrc and edit the line mention above

Changes takes effect when opening a new terminal session or by running

```
source ~/.zshrc
```